# smsManager does not send SMS and it's not requesting permission in the app although I have requested in the code

Tags: android, smsmanager

I am relatively new to android studio and I have some issues with smsManager. It does not request permissions for SMS when i launch the app and doesn't send SMS. The code has no errors either. This is my code:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ViolationActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
public void sendSMS() {
    String /*message = IDNumber.getText().toString();
            message = violationPicker.getSelectedItem().toString();*/
            message = additional_info.getText().toString();
    String number = PhoneNumber.getText().toString();
    SmsManager mySmsmanager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    mySmsmanager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
    Button btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(v->sendSMS());
}
```

All necessary permissions are requested in the manifest.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. The individual pieces you've mentioned and shown would be correct in isolation, so we need to see how it's all interacting.

Comment: What other part do you think I should add? Because the rest of the code in the activity doesn't have much to do with the smsManager code

Comment: I can't really answer that, specifically. Please consult the [mcve] page for guidance in putting together your example.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling button click inside the sendSms method.

I have done what you wanted to achieve and it works.

Here is my code snippet.

First ensure you have the following permission in your manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Then in your activity have the following method

```
 public void sendSMS(String message, String number) {
    SmsManager mySmsmanager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    mySmsmanager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
}
```

Request permission and send message and number to your sendSms method when user clicks the button.

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
   
    Button btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    EditText edMessage = findViewById(R.id.edMessage);
    EditText edNumber = findViewById(R.id.edPhoneNumber);


    //listen to button click
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(view -> {

        //get message and number
        String message = edMessage.getText().toString();
        String number = edNumber.getText().toString();

        //pass your message and number to sendSms method
        sendSMS(message, number);

    });
```

The whole snippet:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        Button btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        EditText edMessage = findViewById(R.id.edMessage);
        EditText edNumber = findViewById(R.id.edPhoneNumber);


        //listen to button click
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            //get message and number
            String message = edMessage.getText().toString();
            String number = edNumber.getText().toString();

            //pass your message and number to sendSms method
            sendSMS(message, number);

        });

    }

    public void sendSMS(String message, String number) {
        SmsManager mySmsmanager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        mySmsmanager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
    }

}
```